# Trying to display content based on JSON type, no controller w/ angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-controller, ng-show

I have a JSON file that will contain either an array of objects or a string. I am trying to get this to display based on what JSON type is there.

JSON file,

scenario 1 JSON

```
"thing":{"important":"a giant banana"}
```

scenario 2 JSON

```
"thing":{"important":[
{"one":"one banana"},
{"two":"two banana"}
]}
```

so I attempted,

```
<p ng-show='angular.isString(thing.important)'>Hey guy im a string</p>
```

and

```
<p ng-show="typeof thing.important === 'string'">Hey guy im a string</p>
```

but of course neither worked, how can I place something in an ng-show to display based on the type from the JSON(array or string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not access Javascript method directly on the HTML, because `$scope` is only exposed to view and whatever you tried in `{{}}` find the expression in `$scope` of a controller and evaluates it.

If you wanted to access the object/methods available directly on the Javascript to the view then you should use put those object into the `$scope` property & then its accessible from the UI.

**HTML**

```
<p ng-show='angular.isString(thing.important)'>Hey guy im a string</p>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.angular = angular; //but this is not preferred way to do it.
```

The other way is you could call the method inside a `ng-show` & that will communicate with native method/object.

**HTML**

```
<p ng-show="checkStringType(thing.important)">Hey guy im a string</p>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.checkStringType = function(val){
     return typeof val === 'string'; //preferred way to achieve this thing.
};
```

Comment: ended up placing the logic in the controller. p much as shown, thanks.

Comment: @imnothardcore Glad to help you ..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're passing the JSON, but you need to parse it first...

Suppose we store de JSON in a variable

```
var things = '{"thing":{"important":"a giant banana"} }'
```

Then we'd need to parse it in the HTML

```
<p ng-show='typeof JSON.parse(things).thing.important ==="string"'>Hey guy im a string</p>
```